# copy folder in qml custom build step never ends

Tags: qt, qml, qmake

I have a custom build step for my qml project
[image]

But when I build the command never returns

```
15:28:52: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
15:28:52: Starting: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" C:\Users\G Labdon Std\Documents\Creator\Testing\SingletonTest\MySingleton C:\Users\G Labdon Std\Documents\Creator\Testing\build-SingletonTest-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\MySingleton /Y /I
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is the actual copy command written there?

Comment: What this step should do?

Comment: There is an xcopy command in the arguments box - the diagram is not showing it - the command is supposed to copy the folder MySingleton to the deployment folder

Comment: Use `cmd /C` or cmd will not quit after the command is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Command** textbox put `XCOPY` instead of `cmd`.

Let the arguments be there in **Arguments** textbox (source, destination and other options).

Something like below.

Command: XCOPY

Arguments: C:\Users\XXXXXX\test1 C:\Users\XXXXX\test2 /Y /I